# Duplicate subnodes based on subelement value

Tags: xslt

How can one perform a conditional copy on xslt. For instance

```
<Person>
   <Name>John</Name>
   <Sex>M</Sex>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Name>Jane</Name>
    <Sex>F</Sex>
</Person>
```

So if Name = "John" then:

```
<Person>
   <Name>John</Name>
   <Sex>M</Sex>
</Person>
<Copied>
   <Name>John</Name>
   <Sex>M</Sex>
</Copied>
<Person>
    <Name>Jane</Name>
    <Sex>F</Sex>
</Person>
```

So far i have this bit of xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="Person">
    <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <Copied>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </Copied>
</xsl:template>
```

This is also makes a copy for "jane" how can conditionally duplicate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
<xsl:template match="Person">
    <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="Name='John'">
        <Copied>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </Copied>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Or perhaps:

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person[Name='John']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <Copied>
           <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </Copied>
</xsl:template>
```